# ansible - Showing warning "conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters”

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
- name: creating  task 
  shell: my_commnad
  when: ns.stdout.find('{{lookup('env',env')}}') == -1
```

warning

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found:
ns.stdout.find("{{lookup('env','NAMESPACE')}}") == -1
```

my playbook showing Warning "conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters".The task is to run the shell command if a paricular env is not present . how should I avoid this warning and keep task working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never nest `{{...}}` markers inside a Jinja templating context. The arguments to the `when` keyword are implicitly inside a Jinja context, so you don't need any `{{...}}` markers. Just write e.g:

```
when: ns.stdout.find(lookup('env','NAMESPACE')) == -1
```